# Определения количества определенных записей в 2 таблицах.

Tags: sqlite, mysql, interbase, firebird, sql

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты!
Вывожу первые 30 строк некоторых данных 2 таблиц:

```
select MESS_DATE, SENDER, CAPTION
from REC_MESS_TABLE
where addressee='1'

union all

select MESS_DATE, ADDRESSEE, CAPTION
from REPORTEDLY_TABLE
where SENDER='1'

order by 1 desc rows 1 to 30
```

Вопрос: как узнать сколько всего строк в этой выборке?
Использую firebird 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог сделать следующим образом:

```
select count(*) from
(select MESS_DATE, SENDER, CAPTION
from REC_MESS_TABLE
where addressee='1'

union all

select MESS_DATE, ADDRESSEE, CAPTION
from REPORTEDLY_TABLE
where SENDER='1'

order by 1 desc)
```

Есть ли у кого-нибудь более лучший способ?